# Why does Random class have no minimal complete definition

Tags: haskell, random

[This page](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.2.1/docs/System-Random.html#v:randomR) states that the minimal complete definition of the Random class is "Nothing"

But if I don't provide them, they don't work:

```
data Color = Red | Blue deriving (Bounded, Show)

instance Random Color
```

yields the compiler warning:

```
test.hs:5:10: warning: [-Wmissing-methods]
    • No explicit implementation for
        ‘randomR’ and ‘random’
    • In the instance declaration for ‘Random Color’
  |
5 | instance Random Color
```

and when I run the code I get an error:

```
*Main> let g = mkStdGen 100
*Main> (fst $ random g) :: Color
*** Exception: test.hs:5:10-21: No instance nor default method for class operation random
```

Why aren't `random` and `randomR` listed under the minimal complete definition?

Comment: Notice that up to documentation `Random` type class should not be used any more in favor of `Uniform` and `UniformRange`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is a good question. And the answer is: you are using an older version of `random`, because starting with `random-1.2` your code would not compile and would produce a compile time error, along the lines of:

```hs
    • Could not deduce (UniformRange Color)
        arising from a use of ‘System.Random.$dmrandomR’
      from the context: RandomGen g
        bound by the type signature for:
                   randomR :: forall g.
                              RandomGen g =>
```

Prior to `random-1.2` there used to be no implementation for `random` and `randomR`, so [compiler required implementation for those functions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html#t:Random) in a form of a compilation warning. However, starting with random-1.2 there is a default implementation that uses `DefaultSignatures` extension, which means your `instance Random Color` will compile without explicit implementation for `random` and `randomR` only if your type also has `Uniform` and `UniformRange` instances. For that reason compiler no longer shows `random` and `randomR` as required.

**Edit**

Starting with `random-1.2.1` you can create an instance using nice helper functions `uniformEnumM` and `uniformEnumRM`:

```
import System.Random.Stateful

data Color = Red | Blue deriving (Bounded, Enum, Show)

instance Uniform Color where
  uniformM = uniformEnumM

instance Uniform Color where
  uniformRM = uniformEnumRM

instance Random Color
```

Comment: So the functions are not listed as minimal requirements, because they are not needed to compile, even though they will give warnings and run time errors?

Comment: @bwroga no, the functions [**are** / were listed](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html#t:Random) as minimal requirements! Only, this has changed in the most recent versions of the package, which is what you looked up in the online docs but don't seem to be actually using.

Comment: @bwroga, as leftaroundabout pointed out, you are looking at documentation for newer version of the library (random-1.2.1), but you are using an older version (random-1.1)